# SQL Server Set Based Division Among Sets?

Tags: sql-server, math, division

I have three tables and am trying to determine if the CountCol values in @tableA divided by the CountCol values in @tableB have a clean remainder of CountCol values from @tableC. From my table stuff below, I would just have a result set showing one row with KeyCol of 100. I might be thinking about this wrong, can anyone help?

Thanks.

```
Declare @tableA Table ( KeyCol Int , CountCol Int )
Declare @tableB Table ( KeyCol Int , CountCol Int )
Declare @tableC Table ( KeyCol Int , CountCol Int )
Insert Into @tableA Values ( 100 , 12 )
Insert Into @tableA Values ( 101 , 11 )
Insert Into @tableB Values ( 100 , 3 )
Insert Into @tableB Values ( 101 , 3 )
Insert Into @tableC Values ( 100 , 4 )
Insert Into @tableC Values ( 101 , 4 )
```

Comment: Why are there three tables when it probably should be one? What is the underlying problem to solve? Homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be slow for big tables, but there probably is no better way:

```
SELECT
    A.KeyCol AS A_KeyCol,
    A.CountCol AS A_CountCol,
    B.KeyCol AS B_KeyCol,
    B.CountCol AS B_CountCol,
    C.KeyCol AS C_KeyCol,
    C.CountCol AS C_CountCol
FROM B
CROSS JOIN C
INNER JOIN A ON A.CountCol = B.CountCol * C.CountCol
```

It looks at every combination of values from B and C, and checks if there is a value in A that is their product.

Comment: I wish I could give two checkmarks. I got value from your response and btilly's also.

Answer (score 1):

You have not said it, but I'm going to guess that you want `KeyCol` to also match.  If so, then the following should work:

```
SELECT
FROM A
  JOIN B
    ON a.KeyCol = b.KeyCol
      /* Add mod check here? */
  JOIN C
    ON a.KeyCol = c.KeyCol
WHERE a.CountCol = b.CountCol + C.CountCol
```

If it is possible to have many rows in `b` and `c` for a single row in `a`, then it may be much more efficient to replace `/* Add mod check here? */` with:

```
      AND a.KeyCol % b.KeyCol = 0
```

However if the joins are all 1-1, then this will likely be slower, not faster.

Comment: I wish I could give two checkmarks. I got value from your response and MizardX's also.